# C++, insert substring at specific place of a string

Tags: c++, string

I was trying to insert a substring into a string in C++ using

```
mystr = std::string("This is a '%s' string", "beautiful");
```

But it doesn't work...

Do I really have to rely on the `stringstream` option if I am to use the syntax `%s`, or am I using the syntax incorrectly?

Comment: `mystr = std::string("This is a ") + std::string("beautiful") + std::string(" string");`?

Comment: The documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: I'm actually regretting m initial downvote, apparently the question is about a simple (and may be common) confusion, that can be clarified easily.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think it is reasonable to expect people to at least read the documentation for any function they use before posting a question about it tbh. If something doesn't work, looking it up in a reference manual should be automatic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing `printf()` family format strings with `std::string` construction syntax. These format strings aren't supported generally.

There are various options as pointed out in the other answers.

---

To use `printf()` style format strings natively with a `char*` buffer you can use [`snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

```
#include <iostream>  

int main(){
    size_t size = snprintf( NULL, 0, "This is a '%s' string", "beautiful") + 1;
    std::string mystring(size,0x00);
    snprintf( &mystring[0], size, "This is a '%s' string", "beautiful");
    std::cout << mystring << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06c9fce0a9451cff)

Answer (score 2):

You can insert with [`std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert)

```
std::string mystr{"This is a  string"};
mystr.insert(10, std::string("beautiful"));
```

or

```
mystr = std::string("This is a ") + "beautiful" + " string";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string mystr{ "This is a  string" };
    mystr.insert(10, "beautiful");
    cout << mystr << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way (requires boost)

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

auto s = (boost::format("this is a %1% string") % "beautiful").str();
```